# How to include programmer role in resume when official job title was different?

Tags: title

I had a job out of college where the generic title of the job was 'technologist'.

However in my job I mainly programmed. It wasn't really on a software project but for the entirety of my job I was involved in some form of programming, whether it was using visual basic for automation, using various languages for data mining, or database programming.

Of course I've included this in my job descriptions but could I include programmer in my job title? Maybe something like 'technologist / programmer' or 'technologist / programmer analyst'?

Comment: Who cares about jobs titles anymore? Surely the job function is more important. Otherwise we call people an "environment cleansing operative" etc..  Oh !**K we do?!

Answer (score 7):

In your resume,  you should be briefly  describing what each job entailed and mentioning a few of the more impressive things you accomplished, not just giving the job title -- precisely because job titles rarely tell the whole story, and because their meaning differs from company to company.

Answer (score 3):

I would put it down as Programmer with the Organisations Job Title in Brackets

Programmer (Technologist)

This is what I did for my first job where my Grade was Research Assistant and Later Experimental Officer.

Answer (score 1):

Put it at the end
Put your important duties next to a bullet so the stand out

month/year - present    Comany X   tile: Technologist

- Programming
  ...
- Lab tech
  ...